# How can I list all files and folders beyond a specified size limit?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

In a partition I have several files and folders, and I can list all those file sizes with `du` like this:

```
du -h
```

But how can I list all the files which are beyond a specific disk space size like 5MB?

Comment: Use find `find /path -type f -size +5M -exec ls -lh {} \;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a straight-forward solution in bash, which analyzes the size of both files and folders:

```
#!/bin/bash

folder="$1"
limit="$2"

IFS=$'\n'
for item in `find "$folder"`; do
    size=$(du -s "$item" | cut -f1)
    if [ $size -gt $limit ]; then
        echo $item
    fi
done
```

first param is the target folder to examine
second param is the limit in kilobytes, where 1K=1024 bytes.

Comment: hi just now i saw this , i will try and let you know .

Comment: well I am getting this errors bro . .Moviz/s.sh: 9: [: -gt: unexpected operator
du: cannot access `ter': No such file or directory
But things were there actually . I think we need more eye here .

Comment: @snow sounds weird, I've tested this script on my ~/Musik folder, where there is plenty of files with spaces and may be some other "unusual" characters in path - all okay. How do you run the script? Have you specified folder and limit arguments? I've not made any checks on them to keep it simple. Your are supposed to run it like this: `./findLargeItems.sh ~/Music 10000`. Don't forget to quote path or backslash spaces in it: `"/home/user/random folder"` or /home/user/random\ folder. I guess you know all this, but just in case.

Answer (score 10):

```
find /home/stephenm/ -maxdepth 1 -size +20k -exec du -h {} \;
```

That should list anything over 20k in /home/stephenm

to recurse into sub directorys drop the `-maxdepth 1` option.

Comment: Yeah it Nice  and working . May I get a way with du also please .

Comment: @snow I don't think du can do it on its own I maybe wrong I just looked at the manual.

Comment: @snow, see a solution with du (I mean where it is used to analyze size) below, though the solution in Stephen's answer is apparently more elegant - I should definitely read over `man find` again.

Comment: @snow Wait a minute. If I'm right neither this answer nor Terry's comment take the size of folders into account - they are just for files.

Comment: @pavel A Yes as i have seen its working for files & not working for folders .

Answer (score 1):

Be careful: `du` does not print the size of a file, it gives you an estimate of file space usage.

You can create a 10 MB file, which uses much less:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=file seek=10M count=1 bs=1
stat -c %s file
ls -lh file
du -h file
cat file | wc
```

An example is a compressed file that uses less space on disk that its size, of like the example above a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file).

In the example above, `find . -type f -size +5M` will output `file` even if `du` is much less than 5M.

If you know you do not have newlines in your filenames, you can filter the output of `find` with:

```
find . -type f -size +5M | while IFS= read -r file; do
  du=$(du -k "$file")
  size="${du%%$(printf "\t")*}"
  if test $size -gt $((5 * 1024)); then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

If you can have newlines in your filenames, you could use this GNU extension, but then use something else than `echo` in the loop:

```
find . -type f -size +5M -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  du=$(du -k "$file")
  size="${du%%$(printf "\t")*}"
  if test $size -gt $((5 * 1024)); then
    echo "$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Good point about the actual and apparent file sizes, though I doubt TS has any. B/w, you can view the apparent file size with du as well: `du --apparent <file>` in which case the reported size will be the same as with `ls`.